# Rename the column components(bulk) in SQL

Tags: mysql, excel, database, batch-rename, popsql

I retrieved a data which has chemical compounds and related data in CSV. I am using SQL for sorting and retrieving the data that I want and I am very new to this.

The issue I am facing is that the compounds are named as `compund_1`, `compound_2`, and I want to rename them to their respective compound name( e.g.: `compound_1` is Nicotine, `compound_2` is Aspirin).

The issue is there are over 5500 of these and I'd like to know if it's possible for me to replace the names in bulk.

Comment: Source data must be stored unchanged. If you have a table which stores the relation between formalized name `compound_N` and its real name then the name must be substituted in the retrieving query.

Comment: Consider having a mapping table

Comment: I do not have a table that stores the relation between the compound and the real name. I guess I should create one.

Answer (score 0):

you can create  a table with columns
required to store chemical compounds and related data.

import the csv file to this table.

create another csv  file with compounds column and their names (asprin...).

import  this  csv file into the table. that will  replace all compound_1  ... with  their names.

Comment: I'll definitely try this.